How to pass device ID from Electron main process to Vue app via IPC?
I'm working on an Electron app where I need to send a device ID from the Electron main process to a Vue app. The device ID is generated based on system information, and I'm trying to pass it to the Vue app when it loads. However, the device ID isn't being received in the Vue app. Here are the relevant parts of my code:
  import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron';
import si from 'systeminformation';
import * as path from "path";

async function getDeviceId() {
    try {
        const disks = await si.diskLayout();
        return disks.length > 0 ? disks[0].serialNum : 'NoDiskFound';
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to get disk information:', error);
        return 'ErrorGeneratingId';
    }
}

function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadFile('loader.html');

    mainWindow.webContents.once('did-finish-load', async () => {
        const deviceId = await getDeviceId();
        mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8080').then(() => {
            mainWindow.webContents.once('did-finish-load', () => {
                mainWindow.webContents.send('device-id', deviceId);
                console.log("Sending device ID to renderer:", deviceId);
                mainWindow.show();
            });
        });
    });
}


app.on('ready', createWindow);

Preload script (preload.ts):
  import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';

console.log("Preload script is running");
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
    receiveDeviceId: (callback: (arg0: any) => void) => {
        ipcRenderer.on('device-id', (event, deviceId) => {
            console.log("Device ID received in preload:", deviceId);
            callback(deviceId);
        });
    }
});
    
    console.log('IPC setup should be complete now');

on the vue component in this url http://localhost:8080/auth/signup
 onMounted(() => {
            console.log(window);
            window.electron.receiveDeviceId((receivedDeviceId) => {
                deviceId.value = receivedDeviceId;
                console.log('Device ID received:', deviceId.value);
            });
        });

I'm not receiving the device ID in the Vue app. The console.log('Device ID received:', deviceId.value); does not print device ID. I'm also not sure if the IPC message is being sent at the right time or being lost during the page load or it actually being sent. I've checked that the preload.js is properly loaded and the IPC setup message is printed in the console.
Any suggestions or insights regarding this would be greatly appreciated!

Does this answer your question? Send response to ipcRenderer from ipcMain

And your code doesn't work because you send the message before your URL is loaded.
